# Can a hacker create a MITM attack by extracting a cert from the client's truststore?

Tags: java, security, ssl, reverse-engineering

I am relatively new to SSL, and after finally finishing a code implementation of SSL in Java, I am curious about potential flaws.

My code consists of two `SSLSockets` (one of which is a `SSLServerSocket` on the server-end), and one-way SSL authentication is used. The server contains a KeyStore with a CA-signed certificate, and the client has a TrustStore with the same CA-signed certificate. If my understanding is correct, the SSL handshake, among numerous other things, ensures that the peer certificate is legitimate and that it matches the certificate in the client's TrustStore.

With this knowledge, would it be possible for someone to decompile my client-side code and extract the CA-signed certificate from the TrustStore file with the intent of creating a malicious server with a KeyStore containing the CA-signed certificate? If my logic is correct, this would allow a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: No. When the server sends its certificate it also sends a CertificateVerify message which is signed by the private key. If the hacker doesn't have the private key he can't do that.

Comment: Certificates are public knowledge anyway. What is important is to secure the private key related to them. Once someone gets the private key then yes, it can impersonate that specific identity.

Answer (score 2):

Certificates in the trust store are only used to verify if a server certificate is valid, i.e. locally trusted. These CA certificates are usually public anyway, i.e. the attacker does not need to extract it from the clients trust store.

It would be differently if the attacker would be able to inject a new CA certificate into the clients trust store. In this case the client would also trust certificates issued by the attackers CA which makes it possible for the attacker to impersonate and to MITM other sites.